How to triple boot Windows, Ubuntu and Arch
I have a laptop which came pre-installed with Windows 10 (500GB SSD). Last year, I dual booted that laptop with Ubuntu by shrinking my Windows 10 volume. I am in the process of installing Arch Linux to try a different distribution. I want to have 1 bootloader with the options to boot from Ubuntu, Windows and Arch but I am struggling to get that to work.

Right now I have one GRUB bootloader in which I choose from booting Windows or Linux. My current setup is:
sda
    sda1    [EFI system partition]
    sda2    [Windows reserved partition]
    sda3    [Windows data partition]
    sda4    [Ubuntu root partition]
    sda4    [swap partition]
    sda5    [Dell XPS support (not sure what this is)]


I shrunk my Windows data partition to allow for more free space and I only created an Arch root partition, since I already have a BOOT and SWAP partition from Ubuntu.

I wanted my system to look like this:
sda
    sda1    [EFI system partition]
    sda2    [Windows reserved partition]
    sda3    [Windows data partition]
    sda4    [Ubuntu root partition]
    sda4    [swap partition]
    sda5    [Arch root partition]
    sda6    [Dell XPS support (not sure what this is)]


I mounted my partition, installed the essential software, configured dates and localisation and skipped the installing grub part on Arch. I unmounted everything and rebooted.

I booted to my Ubuntu partition to add Arch to the bootloader. I ran
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

on Ubuntu and rebooted. I was hoping to see my Arch installation on the bootloader but nothing was showing.

This is the output of my sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub`
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg`
Generating grub configuration file...
Found linux image: /boot/linuz-6.8.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.mg-6.8.0-48-generic
Found linux image: /boot/linuz-6.8.0-47-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.mg-6.8.0-47-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done


This is the output from running sudo lsblk -o FSTYPE,PARTTYPE /dev/sda5:
FSTYPE  PARTTYPE
ext4    0fc63daf-8483-4772-8e79-3d69d8477de4



This is the output from running sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda5:


tune2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          /mnt
Filesystem UUID:          2e332f66-69c8-46f4-8716-f8a7c3f5ff7a
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index FEATURE_C12 filetype extent 64bit flex_bg metadata_csum_seed sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              4833280
Block count:              19309568
Reserved block count:     965478
Overhead clusters:        447787
Free blocks:              18218662
Free inodes:              4776850
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Group descriptor size:    64
Reserved GDT blocks:      1024
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Fri Dec  6 16:12:09 2024
Last mount time:          Fri Dec  6 16:12:58 2024
Last write time:          Fri Dec  6 16:25:18 2024
Mount count:              1
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Fri Dec  6 16:12:09 2024
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          3796 MB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     32
Desired extra isize:      32
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      8f536137-3e7d-4f09-a48d-bd545c8fda07
Journal backup:           inode blocks
Checksum type:            crc32c
Checksum:                 0x158985b1
Checksum seed:            0x57873190

Does anyone have any idea why?

Please [edit] and add the output of grub-mkconfig. Not the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file, just the output you saw on the terminal. Was your Arch installation recognized? You said you have a boot partition, but you don't show it. Do you really have a separate /boot and, if so, which one is it and how does Arch use it? Finally, and probably most importantly, did you run grub-install?

@terdon I don't think he should (have) run grub-install, since he already has Ubuntu and apparently he want to use one single "shared" grub (and he is doing the right thing by avoiding "managing" it from Arch).

I kinda wonder what you were referring to with went to my Ubuntu partition to add Arch to the bootloader btw (just grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg, maybe?).

@TomYan I am far, far from sure, and I haven't looked at grub in quite a few years now but I do remember always needing to run either update-grub or grub-install after generating the grub.cfg file.

@terdon Uhm update-grub is an Ubuntu (or Debian, idr) thing that is the "proper" command to run (instead of grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg) to generate/update /boot/grub/grub.cfg. I never bothered to check what's its real purpose though (maybe just to avoid having to type -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg). And no, grub-install is never needed just after generating the grub.cfg file. One only needs to re-install grub when /boot is "moved" (e.g. out from or to a separate partition or so), so that the EFI executable / "core.img" would look at the right place for grub.cfg et al.

@terdon I was under the impression that my EFI partition is the boot partition. Am I mistaken to assume so? I also edited my question, thank you for pointing it out.

@TomYan I meant that I booted into Ubuntu and executed sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

@Coderless "boot partition" is IMHO kind of a vague term, but usually with that people refers to the dedicated partition, if any, for /boot. But it sounds to me that you do not have any dedicated partition(s) for /boot for either distros (according to my recent experience with Ubuntu, that's like the default, so expected).

Fair enough, thanks @TomYan. I admit I have never looked into bootloaders in any detail, and haven't had to play around with mine for a few years thanks to Arch and its rolling updates. I'm sure you're right and Coderless should ignore my question about grub-install.

Yeah, what Tom said, @Coderless. Yes, the EFI is a partition your system will boot from, but "Boot partition" in the *nix world usually refers to a dedicated partition mounted at /boot. Some setups have EFI mounted there, others mount it at /boot/EFI others do yet another thing, which is why your mention of a boot partition was confusing.

@terdon I see, thank you for explaining

@Coderless Can you also add the output of sudo lsblk -o FSTYPE,PARTTYPE /dev/sda5 to your post? (Btw, did you maybe forget to install a kernel package, such as linux, which is not pulled in by the base meta-package, when you install Arch?)

Arch is known for using cutting-edge features earlier than Ubuntu. It is quite possible that Arch uses cool new ext4 features which are not yet supported by the os-prober and/or the GRUB that is supplied by Ubuntu. Please add the output of tune2fs -l /dev/sda5 (run from Ubuntu) to your question. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=285570https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=285570 might be related.

@TomTan I added both outputs

This page has an example Arch grub boot stanza to add to 40_custom. But looking at UUIDs, the set root is to the ESP as it has the format of an ESP type partition. So does Arch expect some files in ESP? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076205&page=57

@oldfred In Arch it's totally (as in, no "default" unless you use some "installer") up to you whether the ESP should be used for /boot, and when it is, it should be the grub "root".

I think what @Hermann suggested is most likely the cause of the problem. (At least for now I cannot think of anything else.) Btw you may try to run something like ls (hd0,gpt5)/ in the grub shell to see if the Arch root filesystem can be read by grub (although that probably does not confirm os-prober's capability at the same time -- and I have no idea if that depends on the running kernel of the system). (Hmm but kernel 6.8.0 probably means that you are on Ubuntu Noble? Which apparently ships grub 2.12...)

That is odd. tune2fs version 1.46.5 is shipped with Ubuntu 22.04. The running kernel version 6.8.0 suggests Ubuntu 24.04. Can you update the e2fsprogs package to version 1.47.0? Then tune2fs will recognize the ext4 FEATURE_C12 as the orphan_file feature. You can then use tune2fs -O ^orphan_file /dev/sda5 to disable the feature which will probably help os-prober and GRUB. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1497523/feature-c12-e2fsck-get-a-newer-version-of-e2fsck

First Things First: Partition Layout
I would like to tell you you are on the right track.  A couple things though:

On an EFI based system, the EFI partition is not necessarily the /boot mountpoint or directory

Since you want to control booting from Ubuntu, work only in Ubuntu after installing Arch.
/boot should be formatted fat32 and only have kernels and RAM images (installed via grub).
It should have 2 sub directories:

/boot/efi, or /boot/EFI - The bootloading shims/*.efi files are stored here in vendor created folders.
/boot/grub - stores the Grub config files and modules created from update-grub




You should not share swap partitions between distributions, although I've seen it done.  In case you have issues, create multiple swaps
Check the /etc/fstab file to see if only /boot is mounted, or if boot/efi has a separate entry

Secondly: Arch Install
When doing booting this way, one cannot have multiple /boot directories.  All the EFI loaders need to reside in the same EFI entry point

Format /dev/sda5 and start over
Proceed with the Arch handbook  until Section 1.9

Ignore the example layout and mount the /boot mount point by pointing it to the location of the /boot directory on the Ubuntu install.
If you need to, perform a ls -al /boot in Ubuntu to see how it's laid out, and then refer to EFI System Partition - Section 4.1 on the Arch Wiki.  Reminder: Typical here refers to an Arch typical setup, as in Arch will use the entire disk.
Proceed as normal in the Arch Handbook until Section 3.1.  Copy or rewrite all the /boot related entries from Ubuntu's fstab to Arch's fstab, and then add the relevant parts of the Arch system to Arch's fstab (/, swap, etc.)
Continue in the Arch Handbook as normal again until Section 3.8, click Boot Loader and then Grub.

In step 1: Mount the EFI System Partition, mount Ubuntu's location
Perform the command as follows: grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=<Ubuntu's EFI location> One doesn't need the --bootloader-id argument because the Default will be the Vendor Supplied folder name of Arch I believe.




Edit  Arch's /etc/defaults/grub: Add the following: GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
Generate the config file: grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg. Note: Until We can fix it in Ubuntu, Arch's Grub has taken over. If one doesnt want that, change GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true before generating the config file.  You'll then need a Ubuntu Live CD USB to get back into your Ubuntu install.
From Arch's Grub, Choose Ubuntu: If everything went well, you'll see Ubuntu's Grub Menu without Arch

Login to Ubuntu, mount the shared /boot partition and issue sudo update-grub.  At this point, Ubuntu's version of Grub will replace Arch's, and since os-prober is true in Ubuntu Arch gets added.



Caveats
With a shared /boot partition, there is no way to turn off OS Prober, as grub can only read one generated .cfg file, but because you are stub loading the EFI files Grub's boot menu will be seen independently by each OS.  What is actually happening is this:

Grub (Either version) sees the following:

/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi - Windows EFI loader
/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi - Ubuntu EFI Loader for Grub 2
/boot/efi/EFI/arch/grubx64.efi - Arch's EFI Loader for Grub 2


The above are only seen because we took the time to install Grub in both OS'es

The drawback here is that you can't use only one grub, because there is no way to create the file paths above in the alternate OS, unless you create a manual stanza which in my opinion is a major pain, although doable.  See this question on 40.custom if you'd rather use grub only once.  Be aware the custom method also requires multiple /boot directories due to the configfile directive.




Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
